# Postfix в FreeBSD, отправка почты через почтовые программы

Tags: postfix, администрирование, freebsd

Здравствуйте.
Настраивал почтовый сервер postfix по инструкции [Postfix + Dovecot + Postfixadmin](http://asy.org.ua/postfix-dovecot-postfixadmin/).

Сделал все как там описано. Почта принимается. И если отправлять из `localhost`, через сайт, то почта отправляется. Проблемы только тогда, когда отправляется почта из почтовых программ.

Как мне решить эту проблему? 
Спасибо.

Comment: При отправке клиентом, что он пишет в качестве ошибки?

Comment: на сервере выполнить_netstat -ntupl_

Comment: ``[root@spendhunters ~]# netstat -ntupl ``  ``netstat: illegal option -- t``

Comment: простите )) этж bsd тогда     sockstat -l

Comment: а тут:    postconf | grep my

Comment: Выложил тут http://spendhunters.ru/info3.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

№1. Почему в конфиге:

```
myhostname = mail.spendhunters.ru
```

хотя мне кажется должен быть:

```
myhostname = spendhunters.ru
```

№2. Почемутут

```
# nslookup -type=mx spendhunters.ru ns5.ukrdns.bizServer:     ns5.ukrdns.bizAddress:    78.109.16.107#53spendhunters.ru mail exchanger = 9 spendhunters.ru.
```

хотя должен быть:

```
spendhunters.ru mail exchanger = 9 mail.spendhunters.ru.
```

Comment: я пробовал spendhunters.ru и mail.spendhunters.ru  не помогло

Comment: давай попробуем, как  нужно (описал выше), потом по ошибкам будет понятно, что не так.

Comment: и, конечно, как говорил http://admin.hashcode.ru/users/1439/jaurи из postconf     smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destinationвидно, что сперва разрешаются mynetworks, потом разрешаются sasl_authenticated, потом реджектятся unauth_destination. Из этого следует, что тот, от кого письма не принимаются на отправку либо не в mynetworks, либо не sasl-аутентифицирован.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках постфикс проверьте параметр mynetworks и укажите диапазон адресов, с которых можно отправлять.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.Postfix, как и практически любой другой MTA (Exim, Exchange и т.д.) позволяет использовать себя в качестве, в большинстве своем в двух случаях:

1. клиент имеет IP адрес из подсети, указанной в mynetworks;
2. клиент прошел аутентификацию.

При отправке почты с помощью почтового клиента обычно используется аутентификация с использованием пароля. Насколько мне известно Postfix позволяет использовать для аутентификации две реализации SASL - Cyrus и Dovecot. В статье, ссылку, на которую Вы предоставили, используется Dovecot SASL. Одна из возможных причин того, что почта не отправляется - клиент не проходит аутентификацию или MTA предоставляет способы аутентификации, не поддерживаемые почтовым клиентом. Для решения проблемы рекомендую Вам выполнить несколько проверок:

1. Так как для аутентификации используется Dovecot SASL, проверьте возможность аутентификации с помощью встроенных средств dovecot:

   doveadm auth логин пароль
2. В случае, если аутентификация с помощью doveadm прошла успешно, причину ошибки, в подавляющем большинстве случаев можной найти в логе, как правило, это /var/log/maillog . Для диагностики лучше использоваться максимально простые средства (почтовый клиент таким не является), например nc . Прицепитесь к логу сервера с помощью tail:

   tail -f /var/log/maillog

И отправьте с помощью nc тестовое письмо (по подному из многочисленных howto в Сети). В случае, если выявить причину проблемы самостоятельно не удастся, выложите лог сессии в комментарий к данному письму.